# MySQL join - checking if someone has an entry

Tags: mysql

MYSQL. Let me introduce my tables, minified:

I have a table `users` with the row `id`.

I have a table `tasks` with the rows `id` and `title`.

I have a table `users_tasks`which connects them both, with the rows `id`, `uid` (for users.id) and `tid` (for tasks.id).

Now I want to have a list of ALL tasks PLUS the information if the user with id `6` has been assigned to that task (= if an entry in `users_tasks` exists where `uid` = `6`)

The beginning is simple, get all tasks: `SELECT * FROM tasks` but now what? I tried to continue with a LEFT JOIN to `users_tasks` but the result was too weird to seem the right direction... Do I need something like an conditional join? I'm confused

My favored result would look like this (assuming there are 4 tasks and user 6 is assigned to 1 and 3):

```
tasktitle  | entry for user 6
-----------------------------
task 1     |       1
task 2     |       0
task 3     |       1
task 4     |       0
```

edit for comment to tombom:

```
SELECT
*, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users_tasks ut WHERE tasks.id = ut.tid AND ut.uid = 6)
FROM
tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join at all.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tasks
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users_tasks ut WHERE tasks.id = ut.tid AND ut.uid = 6)
```

This should perform faster than a join, because the `EXISTS ()` returns as soon as a row is found, whereas a join returns all matching rows.

Comment: I have tested this query and it does only show tasks where user 6 is assigned. I want to view ALL tasks plus the information IF user6 has an entry.

Comment: I have managed to solve this with parts from your code. I edited the original post to show the solution which only slightly differs from yours. Thank you, your answer helped me :)